# Unable to left join table on Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I need to execute left joining for some data retrieving. But surprisingly it doesn't give any answer also when I tried to echo something after that it doesn't echo anything.

```
$exam = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->from('qz_exams')
    ->leftJoin('qz_courses', 'qz_courses.id = qz_exams.course_id')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();

foreach ($exam as $item) {
    echo $item->name . '<br>';
}
echo 'BOOM';
```

This is what I tried to do. I have also included `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manage` into my `public/index.php` file with dispatcher. It also does't give any error also. What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that Phalcon Query Builder uses Model name with full namespace, not only table name (like PHQL does). Here is a full working example:

```
$items = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->columns([
        // Fetching only desired columns (prefered way)
        'table1.column1',
        'table1.column2',
        'table2.column1',
        'table2.column2',
        // Or fetching whole objects
        'table1.*',
        'table2.*',    
    ])
    ->from(['table1' => 'YourNamespaces\Table1ModelName'])
    ->leftJoin('YourNamespaces\Table2ModelName', 'table1.id = table2.foreign_key', 'table2')
    ->where('table1.column = :column:', ['column' => $whereValue])
    ->getQuery()->execute();
```

Also I would recommend to debug the results with

```
print_r($exam->toArray());
```

Comment: I have tried your way. I didn't declare any namespace for my models. So I just give only my model name [code](https://ideone.com/Tayf2a).
Even that `echo 'boom'` doesn't print after that.

Comment: Looking at your code print_r($exam.toArray()); you made a silly mistake :)
Should be $exam->toArray()

Comment: Well that I have fixed after I commented :) but still I couldn't get any echo's or print_r

Comment: In your code link there is an error "PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in /home/MAJV1R/prog.php on line 2" Are you making this query in static method or outside of class context? If so you can try using the DI in static way: $di = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault(); More info here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html#accessing-the-di-in-a-static-way

Comment: Have you solved the problem? If so tell us what you did and mark question as answered.

Comment: `->leftJoin('Courses','qz_exams.course_id=qz_course.id','qz_courses')`.it should be `qz_courses.id` instead of `qz_course.id`. Thanks for your help. You saved me from lot of trouble. :)